# Can you call a group of people by a subgroup of 2, and if so then how?

Tags: grammar, word-requests, plurals, plural-suffixes

What I understand:

A way of referring to a group of people by just 1 person can be done with saying [name]-[honorific, if any] tachi. (I seem to be right based on [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/59830/addressing-a-group-of-people-with-tachi-%E3%81%9F%E3%81%A1-and-name-of-one) and [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/30002/hey-bro-how-to-call-out-friends/38533#38533).)

- Eg For the group of the 6 Tanaka siblings with 1st names **Ashanti, Bidatz, Mikoto, Smith, Wesson and Yellow**, assuming you would call each as 1st name-san, you might refer to them as '**Ashanti-san tachi**', which I understand either literally means 'Ashanti-san and the others' or nonsensically literally means 'plural of Ashanti-san' but really means Ashanti-san and the others'.
- Either way I guess 'たち' here is like 'et al'. (I guess it's similar to the Philippine word 'sila', where you'd say 'sila Ashanti' even though 'sila' ordinarily means 'they'. But maybe a better analogy is the Mandarin 们. Idk.)

**Question**: Can you refer to the siblings by **2 of them**, and if so then how would you do so? Perhaps Ashanti-san と Bidatz-san たち?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can say AさんとBさんたち.  It refers to one group of people including both A and B. Technically speaking, however, this is an ambiguous phrase, and it can also refer to "A, and a gruop of people including B". This kind of ambiguity is not usually a problem when there is enough context.

If you used たち twice (AさんたちとBさんたち), it naturally refers to two groups of people.

Comment: oh man thanks i think...it's like...'green keyboard and mouse' where depending on context 'green' can describe both keyboard and mouse or just the keyboard? So here it depends where the tachi describes the whole A and B or just the B...but as you said usually you can tell from the context?